# Chrome webdriver won't open from cron

Tags: python, selenium, cron, beautifulsoup

I have a BeautifulSoup & Selenium script running in Python 2.7 which works perfectly from terminal but will not run as a cron job.

I get the following traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "sel_hourly.py", line 50, in <module>
with closing(Chrome(chrome_options=options)) as driver:
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py", line 69, in __init__
desired_capabilities=desired_capabilities)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 92, in __init__
self.start_session(desired_capabilities, browser_profile)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 179, in start_session
response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, capabilities)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 236, in execute
self.error_handler.check_response(response)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 192, in check_response
raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally
(Driver info: chromedriver=2.25.426924 (649f9b868f6783ec9de71c123212b908bf3b232e),platform=Linux 4.8.0-22-generic x86_64)
```

Line 50, where it starts the failure is the with statement in the following:

```
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("--start-maximized")
with closing(Chrome(chrome_options=options)) as driver:
    driver.get(url)
    # wait for the page to load
    time.sleep(1)
    # store it to string variable
    page_source = driver.page_source
    soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(page_source,'lxml')
```

Could anyone advise on the issue.

Comment: But it works for me when I run it under crontab -e so I must have given it on my system but not on my customer's.  How do I set it?

Comment: @e4c5 I'm sorry but I do not understand why that means it will work on my system when I've entered it but it doesn't run on my customer's system.  I've clearly a lack on understanding of cron but it works on my server when I enter the job using crontab -e.  It then when set

Comment: It's creating the traceback error shown above, whereas on my system the script runs and completes its tasks

Comment: But it does work when I enter it using crontab -e.  Perhaps you could point me to a good primer

Comment: Could you try again with the latest version of chromedriver? I once had a similar issue that was fixed that way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution in the end was to switch to firefox and implement pyvirtualdisplay to mimic the display.